# Get number of post in list array from another class. But It doesn't work?

Tags: java, android

I try to get number of post from arraylist in the class into mainactivity.
But it is wrong .
Here is my code.

```
public static  int countNotify;
    public static List<Notification> bindNotifyData(JsonElement list)
    {
        List<Notification> results= new ArrayList<>();
        JsonObject dataJsonObj = list.getAsJsonObject();
        // get data api from Json array "updates"
        JsonArray notifyJsonArray = dataJsonObj.get("updates").getAsJsonArray();
        ArrayList<Notification> notifyList = new ArrayList<>();
        countNotify=notifyJsonArray.size();
        if(notifyJsonArray != null && notifyJsonArray.size() > 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < notifyJsonArray.size(); i++) {
                JsonObject notifyJson = (JsonObject) notifyJsonArray.get(i);
                Notification notification = new Notification();
                notification.setContent(notifyJson.get("content").getAsString());
                // Convert timestamp to Datetime
                String timestamp= notifyJson.get("time").getAsString();
                notification.setTime(ConvertTimestamp(timestamp));
                results.add(notification);
                // count numbers of the post in the list json array.
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

And in the MainActivity.class

```
 final int count=BindFetchDataHelper.countNotify;
```

But the value of count always is 0

Comment: There is not enough info in your question to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a instance of your class

BindFetchDataHelper bindFetchDataHelper = new BindFetchDataHelper ()

and then call final int count=bindFetchDataHelper.countNotify;

I had the same issue, it should work now.

EDIT

Try like this :

```
public class BindFetchDataHelper {

private static int sTest;



static {
public static  int countNotify=0;

}




public static int getcountNotify() {
    return countNotify;
}

public static void setcountNotify(int setcountNotify) {
    this.countNotify = countNotify;
}

//your others functions
}
```

And now to access variable or to set it :

```
BindFetchDataHelper bindFetchDataHelper = new BindFetchDataHelper ()

bindFetchDataHelper.setcountNotify(YOURVALUE); //set


int whatyourwant = bindFetchDataHelper.getcountNotify(); //get
```

Comment: In the bindNotifyData class. I can't set values of number's posts into variable countNotiffy. any body can help me ?